# Putting function into data frame

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am new to the programming aspect of R, so any help would be sincerely appreciated.

I am trying to create a data frame in which x runs from 0 to 30 (column 1) and for each set of x, t runs from 1 to 20 (column 2). I am trying to make a third column (V) where V is a function of x on the condition that if t=20 V=2*x, and for all other values of t, V=0. The code I am using is

```
    df<-data.frame("x"=rep(0:30, times=20), "t"=rep(1:20, each=31),
           "V"=rep(0, times=620))


    if (df$t==20){
      df$V=df$x*2
    }
```

I keep getting error messages.

Again, any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible solution:

```
df<-data.frame(cbind(x=rep(0:30, times=20),t = rep(1:20, each=31),V=0))
df$V[df$t==20]<-2*df$x[df$t==20]
```

Comment: Thank you. This was awhile ago, when I was still an extreme R novice, but it was definitely helpful.